# Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes) isn't taken into account

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow ignores the "Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes)" configuration. In the response's expired_on, the configuration is taken into account, but not in the access_token's payload (exp-property).

*OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow means, that the grant_type = authorization_code.*

**"Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes)" configuration for the SignupIn flow:** 1440 minutes

**Time of the observation:**
08/02/2019 12:03 (GMT+2)

**Payload in the access_token:**

```
"exp": 1564740156
```

Timestamp = 08/02/2019 12:02 (GMT+2)

**Value in the response of the token-endpoint:**

```
"expires_on": 1564822956
```

Timestamp = 08/03/2019 9:02 (UTC)

**Current solution:**
As workaround, the "Access & ID token lifetimes (minutes)" configuration was set to the default value (60 minutes). Now the "exp" property in the access_token and the "expires_on" property in the response match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this for you, the result was as expected. Here are my steps for your reference.

**1.Set the Aceess&ID token lifetime**

[image]

**2.get authrization code**

```
https://tonyb2ctest.b2clogin.com/tonyb2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_testsignupin&client_id=c3a6429c-017e-4ac7-ae02-1579b3f3fa9c&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient1.as.com&scope=c3a6429c-017e-4ac7-ae02-1579b3f3fa9c&response_type=code&prompt=login
```

**3.get the token**

[image]

[image]

**4.decode the access token**

[image]

The expiration dates are consistent.

Comment: That's exactly what I also did. Seems that they fixed it. I reported it as an issue some weeks ago. :-)